# I can not handle programe exception : play java sound

Tags: java, audio, mp3, wav

I want my Java program to play sounds, but I am having some problems with it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException        {   

    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("PTUK1.mp3"));

    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();    
    clip.open(audioIn);
    clip.start();
    clip.stop();
}
```

---

I am getting the following exception, with "PTKU1.mp3" :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1187)
```

---

With "PTUK2.wav", I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play an mp3!

```
private void playMe(){
try{

 Player player;
File file=new File(“F://a.mp3″);
FileInputStream fis     = new FileInputStream(file);
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

 player = new Player(bis);

 player.play();

 }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.print(“ERROR “+e);
 }

 }
```

Note that:

You Must have jlayer.jar
You Must have mp3plugin.jar
You can get them www.javaextreme.wordpress.com